# I Can't connect to my server on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js

I running a RESTful api node server on my localhost and I can reach it on postman but I cant access to it on my react app and get this error when try to connect:

[image]

what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6000 is considered an unsafe port by Chrome. Just make the port 3000 or something within safe range.

[Ref](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/heads/main/net/base/port_util.cc)

Comment: Restricted Ports: [Same ref with line no.](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/heads/main/net/base/port_util.cc#99)

Answer (score 1):

There is some interesting information on restricted/unsafe ports on this post: https://superuser.com/questions/188058/which-ports-are-considered-unsafe-by-chrome

And an answer on how to turn this setting off in Windows on https://superuser.com/questions/188006/how-to-fix-err-unsafe-port-error-on-chrome-when-browsing-to-unsafe-ports

Alternatively - change your exposed port to outside of the list on the first link.